How to deal with load more button?
I have this question about load more button. The page need to make this "road map": go to search's page, "see" product one by one, click on them and then go back to the search's page. My approach was to click on "load more" button until it doesn't exist anymore, then after scrapt it. But when goes to drive.back(), it's not the same page anymore and the automatic scroll that I did got lost, it doesn't render all the products at all. Also, with manual approach, I saw that if I, for example, click on load more button, select one product of this "other page", click on it, then when I go back to the search's page it doesn't go back to the previous page and I need to click on "load more" button once again. One approach that I thought was to get it with JSON, but the problem is: in my code the user will customize the search, so it will be different pages, never the same. So the url pointing to json would always change. How to make it? Anyway, here is the code:

def extrai_dados_prodirectsports():
    print("entrou")
    url_linha = "https://www.prodirectsport.com/soccer/l/adults/departments-boots/activity-football/brand-adidas/silo-predator/"
    data_planilha = []
    data_pdf = []
    tamanhos = []

    cotacao_libra()  # Supondo que essa função já esteja definida
    i = 0
    driver.get(url_linha)
    
    #Cookies
    WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Accept all cookies']"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id='zonos']")))
    botao_close = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class = 'z-close']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",botao_close)
    #WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='global-popup']")))
    botao = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@aria-label='Close']")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();",botao)
    #driver.implicitly_wait(500000)
            
   
    df_planilha = pd.DataFrame(columns=COLUNAS_PLANILHA)
    #pdf = FPDF()
    #pdf.add_page()
    #pdf.set_font('Arial', 'B', 12)
    
    x = 0 
    driver.maximize_window()
    produtos_lista = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__grid']//div[@class = '_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a")))
    produtos_container = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__grid']")))#driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", produtos_lista)
    while True:
        try:
        # Reencontrar o botão dentro do loop para evitar stale element
            botao_vermais = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-listing__view-more']/button"))
                    )

            if botao_vermais.is_displayed():
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", botao_vermais)
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", botao_vermais)
                
                x += 1
                print(x)
            else:
                driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", produto_container)
                break  # Sai do loop se o botão não for mais exibido
        except StaleElementReferenceException:
            print("Elemento 'Ver mais' tornou-se stale, reencontrando o botão...")
            continue  # Tenta novamente o loop
        except TimeoutException:
            print("Tempo esgotado esperando o botão 'Ver mais'.")
            break
        
    pagina_atual = driver.current_url
            
    for index, value in enumerate(produtos_lista):
        
        driver.get(pagina_atual)
        
        produtos_lista = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class = 'product-listing__grid']//div[@class = '_root_129ai_6 product-listing__grid-item']/a")))    
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", produtos_lista[index])
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.save_screenshot("janela.png")
        imagem_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "img")))
        imagem = imagem_element.get_attribute("src")
        i += 1
        print(i)
        #actions.move_to_element(produtos_lista[index]).perform()
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", produtos_lista[index])
        time.sleep(10)
        driver.save_screenshot("projetoecommerce/screenshots_produtos/prodirectsports/" + str(i) +".png")
        nome_produto = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ml-meta__title"))).text
        print(nome_produto)
        preco = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ml-prices__price"))).text
        preco = re.sub("£", "", preco)
        preco_produto = float(preco) 
        print(preco_produto)
        codigo_produto = driver.current_url.split('-')[-1]
        print(codigo_produto)
        lista_tamanhos = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,  "ml-size__sizes")))
            
        if lista_tamanhos:
            driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", lista_tamanhos)
            for tamanho in lista_tamanhos.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='ml-size__size qa-size-item']"):
                tamanho_produto = tamanho.text
                tamanhos.append(tamanho_produto)
                if "-" in tamanho.text:
                    tamanho_produto = tamanho.text.split('-')[0] 
                    tamanhos.append(tamanho_produto)
                elif "(" in tamanho.text:
                    tamanho_produto = tamanho.text.split('(')[0]
                    tamanhos.append(tamanho_produto)
                else:
                    tamanho_produto = ""
                    tamanhos.append(tamanho_produto)
            print(tamanhos)

        preco_reais = calcula_preco_reais(preco_produto)  # Função precisa estar definida
        preco_venda = calcula_preco_venda(preco_produto)  # Função precisa estar definida

        data_planilha.append({
            'Photo': imagem,
            'Código': codigo_produto,
            'Descrição': nome_produto,
            'Compra': preco_reais,
            'Venda': preco_venda,
            'Tamanhos': tamanhos
            })
        
        driver.back()   
        #driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)")
        
        time.sleep(5)
            
            #driv
    figura = gera_pdf(data_pdf)
    df_planilha = pd.DataFrame(data_planilha)
    df_planilha.to_excel(url_linha + "catalogo.xlsx")    


What would be other approach for it? If I go product by product, then click on load more when I go back it would still if I didn't click on it at all when I go back to the search's page. It seems to me that json scraping would be the best approach, but how can I get the exact url for it? actually, url_line is a parameter of the method, the progra, will read it from a txt file. I got it out for you to test it.

After x1337Loser's beautiful solution, my proposal is going back to Selenium.
The point is to download images by "requests".
This test version loads all the listings while gets 10 images of them.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep
import requests
import  os 

def extrai_dados_prodirectsports(driver):
    print("entrou")
    driver.maximize_window()
    url_linha = "https://www.prodirectsport.com/soccer/l/adults/departments-boots/activity-football/brand-adidas/silo-predator/"
    actions = ActionChains(driver)
    
    driver.get(url_linha)
    sleep(5)

    #Cookies
    cookie = 'auto'
    if cookie == 'auto':
        box = WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//dialog")))
        #sleep(15)
        #box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//dialog")
        box.find_element(By.XPATH,".//div[@class = 'cf1lHZ cf2L3T']/button").click()
    else:
        t = input('Accept cookie manually and key in any key here.  -----  ' )
    sleep(2) 
    
    #load all the listings
    for i in range(30):
        try:
        # Reencontrar o botão dentro do loop para evitar stale element
            botao_vermais = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='product-listing__view-more']/button"))
                    )
        except :
            print("Tempo esgotado esperando o botão 'Ver mais'.")
            break
        else:
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});', botao_vermais)
            actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()#PAGE_DOWN
            actions.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN).perform()#PAGE_DOWN
            sleep(1)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(botao_vermais))
            botao_vermais.click()
            
            print(i+1)  
            sleep(5)
            
    print('\n')

    #get attributes of every listing
    img_urls = []
    product_list = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class ='_root_dgvvn_6 product-listing__grid-item']" )
    print('len(product_list): ',len(product_list),'\n')

    for index, div1 in enumerate(product_list):
        print(index)
        
        imagem_element = div1.find_element(By.XPATH, ".//img")
        imagem_url = imagem_element.get_attribute("src")
        if index % 5 == 0:
            driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "end"});', imagem_element)
        
        info = div1.find_element(By.XPATH, "./a")
        title = info.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[@class ='fw-normal pe-2']").text
        print('title: {}'.format(title))
        price = info.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[@class ='_price_dgvvn_79']").text
        print('price: {}\n'.format(price))
        img_urls.append([index,title,price,imagem_url])
        
    #download images
    imgfolder = 'imagem'  
    os.makedirs(imgfolder, exist_ok=True)

    for i in range(10):#for test only
        print('downloading image {}'.format(i))
        dst_path = '{}\\image_{}.jpg'.format(imgfolder,i)
        im_download(img_urls[i][3], dst_path)
    print('\nend!\n')

def im_download(url, dst_path):

    r = requests.get(url)
    sleep(3)
    #print('response: ', r.status_code)
    if r.status_code == 200:#success
        with open(dst_path, mode="wb") as f:
            f.write(r.content)
        return True
    else:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    extrai_dados_prodirectsports(driver)

Following is an alternative for "get attributes of every listing" stage.
It uses lmxl instead of selenium. As scrolling view is not necessary during the stage, process is done faster than the former way.
import lxml.html
img_urls = []
#get whole html (by Selenium)
page = driver.page_source # type : text
#transfer to lxml
p_root = lxml.html.fromstring(page)

product_list = p_root.xpath("//div[@class ='_root_dgvvn_6 product-listing__grid-item']")
print('len(product_list): ',len(product_list),'\n')
for index, div1 in enumerate(product_list):
    print(index)
    imagem_element = div1.xpath( ".//img")
    attrib = imagem_element[0].attrib# dict of attributes
    imagem_url = attrib['src']
    
    info = div1.xpath( "./a")
    title = info[0].xpath( "./div[@class ='fw-normal pe-2']")[0].text
    print('title: {}'.format(title))
    price_expression = info[0].xpath( "./div[@class ='_price_dgvvn_79']//span")
    price = ''
    for p in price_expression:
        price += p.text + ' '
    print('price: {}\n'.format(price))
    img_urls.append([index,title,price,imagem_url])


Can you check this out if this is what you want? (I saw you talk about JSON URLs)
I used this API endpoint https://www.prodirectsport.com/api/v1/search?location=%2Fsoccer%2Fl%2Fadults%2Fdepartments-boots%2Factivity-football%2Fbrand-adidas%2Fsilo-predator%2F%3Fpg%3D1 to fetch these pieces of information
Code:
import requests
import pandas as pd

image = []
name = []
currentPrice = []
originalPrice = []
colors = []
baseColor = []

for i_s in range(1,7): #Your target endoint has 7 page
    url = f'https://www.prodirectsport.com/api/v1/search?location=%2Fsoccer%2Fl%2Fadults%2Fdepartments-boots%2Factivity-football%2Fbrand-adidas%2Fsilo-predator%2F%3Fpg%3D{i_s}'

    header = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:130.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/130.0"  
    }

    resp = requests.get(url, headers=header).json()
    product_list = resp['products']
    for i in product_list:
        name.append(i['name'])
        image.append(i['media']['thumbnail'])
        currentPrice.append(i['pricing']['current'])
        originalPrice.append(i['pricing']['original'])
        colors.append(i['attributes']['colourway'])
        baseColor.append(i['attributes']['baseColour'])
        print(f"------------------------\nName: {i['name']}\nImage: {i['media']['thumbnail']}\nOriginal price: {i['pricing']['original']}\nCurrent price: {i['pricing']['current']}\nColors: {i['attributes']['colourway']}\nBase color: {i['attributes']['baseColour']}")

get_dict = {
    'Name': name,
    'Image': image,
    'Current Price': currentPrice,
    'Original Price': originalPrice,
    'Colors Available': colors,
    'Base Color': baseColor
}
df_planilha = pd.DataFrame(get_dict)
df_planilha.to_excel("catalogo.xlsx", index=False)

Sample Output:
------------------------
Name: adidas Predator x Bellingham Elite Tongue FG
Image: https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Main/1018916_Main_1871592.jpg
Original price: 250.0
Current price: 250.0
Colors: Core Black/Core Black/Gold Met
Base color: Black
------------------------
Name: adidas Predator x Bellingham League Tongue FG
Image: https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Main/1018917_Main_1876537.jpg
Original price: 90.0
Current price: 90.0
Colors: Core Black/Gold Met/Core Black
Base color: Black
------------------------
Name: adidas Predator Sala IN
Image: https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Main/1018835_Main_1861766.jpg
Original price: 50.0
Current price: 50.0
Colors: Aurora Black/Turbo/Gum 3
Base color: Black
------------------------
Name: adidas Predator Elite Tongue SG
Image: https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Main/1018814_Main_1865133.jpg
Original price: 240.0
Current price: 240.0
Colors: Platin Met/Aurora Black/Carbon
Base color: Grey
------------------------
Name: adidas Predator Elite Tongue FG
Image: https://images.prodirectsport.com/ProductImages/Main/1018813_Main_1865332.jpg
Original price: 240.0
Current price: 240.0
Colors: Platin Met/Aurora Black/Carbon
Base color: Grey

Let me know if I missed something

kind of. But as I've said, the user will customize the url's in an external file and the program will read it, so I cannot "guess" what will be the API endpoint. If only I could get it automatically.

If I make something like  r = requests.get(driver_linha)
json.loads(r)
would work?

or perharps do all the click "load more button" stuff with Selenium and get the JS content rendered with html session? would this work?
